# Hat das Deutsche andere Komma-Regeln als das Englische oder ist dieser Satz fehlerhaft?

Tags: comma

> Trotz Dunkelheit, mangelnder Eleganz und noch offener 
>   Fragen**_**beschreiben die physikalischen Theorien, die ich dargestellt habe, die
>   Welt besser, als es in der Vergangenheit je der Fall war.

Zwischen beschreiben und Fragen muss ein Komma in englisch stehen.

Comment: Zwischen *besser* und *als* darf kein Komma stehen, da es sich um einen Vergleich handelt.

Comment: Wieso sollten zwei verschiedene Sprachen überhaupt gleiche Kommaregeln haben?

Comment: Englisch hat überhaupt keine Komma-Regeln. Ich verstehe die Frage nicht. Englisch hat, soweit die breite Masse etwas zusagen hätte, nur "Sprechpausen".

Comment: Was erzählen Sie denn hier wieder für einen Unsinn? https://www.bristol.ac.uk/arts/exercises/grammar/grammar_tutorial/page_06.htm

Answer (score 11):

Ja, Deutsch hat andere Kommaregeln als das Englische. Vollkommen andere.

> For example, you would put a comma here.
>
> Zum Beispiel gibt es in diesem Fall aber kein Komma.

In your sample sentence, a comma is well-placed after "questions" in the English sentence. [Note the comma also here after "sentence"!]

> Despite of darkness, lacking elegance and open questions, the theories I presented above give a better description of the world than others did in the past.

In der deutschen Fassung dieses Satzes gehört hinter "Fragen" aber kein Komma.
[Note also the non-comma after "Satzes"!]

Ähnlich ist es mit Zeitangaben:

> After that event, he decided to stop contacting her.
>
> Nach diesem Vorfall beschloss er, sie nicht mehr anzusprechen.

Grundsätzlich:

Die Komma-Regeln des Englischen sind meist weniger strikt und deutlich intuitiver als die des Deutschen. Die Kommaregeln des Deutschen sind der Schrecken aller Schüler und Deutschlernenden. Wirklich beherrschen tun sie praktisch nur professionelle Schreiber oder sehr, sehr gebildete oder belesene Personen.

Wer sich in das Thema vertiefen will, dem sei empfohlen:

- Duden Ratgeber - Handbuch Zeichensetzung. Der praktische Ratgeber zu Komma, Punkt und anderen Satzzeichen. Bearbeitet von der Dudenredaktion. 2. aktualisierte und überarbeitete Auflage. Dudenverlag Berlin, 2014. - ISBN 978-3-411-74492-3.

Dieses Buch gibt Stoff für viele unterhaltsame und erbauliche Stunden an langen Winterarbenden. Das Buch hat 254 Seiten. Dem Komma sind die Seiten 34-176 gewidmet.

#### Praktische Ratschläge

Ein paar einfache Grundregeln, die man sich leicht merken kann, gibt es trotzdem:

- Relativsätze werden mit Kommas abgetrennt:

> Ein paar einfache Grundregeln, die man sich leicht merken kann, gibt es trotzdem.

- Vor *dass* steht immer ein Komma:

> Man kann sich sehr leicht merken, dass vor *dass* immer ein Komma steht.

(Achtung aber bei *so dass*: *Das Fass hatte ein Loch, so dass der ganze Wein sogleich wieder hinauslief.* - Man kann *so dass* als eigenes Lexem auffassen, das zufällig mit Leerzeichen geschrieben wird. Aber hier verlieren wir uns schon im Gestrüpp der Linguistik, zu dem Kommentator Janka unten noch ein schönes Beispiel hinterlassen hat.)

- Aufzählungen werden mit Komma getrennt, aber das letzte Element, das mit *und* eingeführt wird, dann nicht mehr (anders als das berühmte, eigentlich sehr praktische Oxford-Komma im Englischen):

> Der Hund, die Katze, der Esel und der Hahn machten sich auf den Weg nach Bremen.

- "Infinitiv+zu"-Sätze trennt man mit einem Komma ab:<sup>1</sup>

> Es ist schöner, Kommas richtig zu setzen.
>
> Vergisst man, Kommas zu setzen, hindert man den Leser am flüssigen Lesen.

Leute, die vom Englischen her kommen, sind gut beraten, sich diese Regeln hinter die Ohren zu schreiben, denn diese Dinge sind im Englischen typischerweise anders.

---

<sup>1</sup> Diese Regel wurde in staatlich gesteuerten Rechtschreibempfehlungen zuletzt aufgeweicht, es ist aber immer noch guter - und manche würden sagen: besserer - Usus, hier konsequent ein Komma zu setzen.

Comment: Wie um alles in der Welt würdest du wissen, dass du dort kein Komma setzen sollst?

Comment: @user5389726598465   - In diesem speziellen Fall: Jemand der mit Deutsch aufgewachsen ist, würde überhaupt nicht auf die Idee kommen, dort ein Komma zusetzen. Dort ein Komma zu setzen, ist eine Eigenheit des Englischen. Andere Sprachen (wie Französisch, Italienisch, Bulgarisch, Russisch) würden an einer solche Stelle auch kein Komma setzen, so weit ich sehe.

Comment: Ich habe die ausschweifende Diskussion über Rechtschreibprüfungen, Rechtschreibhoheit u. Ä. in den [Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97788/discussion-on-answer-by-christian-geiselmann-hat-das-deutsche-andere-komma-regel) verschoben. Bitte diskutiert diese Themen dort weiter, und schreibt nur Kommentare, wenn diese zum Ziel haben, die Antwort zu verbessern.

Answer (score 4):

Ja, die Regeln zur Zeichensetzung unterscheiden sich zwischen englischer und deutscher Sprache grundsätzlich. Nicht nur das, sogar die Motivation der Zeichensetzung unterscheidet sich - In der deutschen Sprache gehört die Zeichensetzung zur Grammatik und wird streng von ihr gesteuert - während sie im Englischen eher eine Stilfrage ist und eher von Hausregeln von z.B. Verlagen und Zeitungen geregelt wird (und es dafür jeweils mehrere, sich teilweise widersprechende Regeln gibt), die oft auf der *Sprachrhythmik* statt auf der Grammatik basieren.

Zu deiner speziellen Frage: Das *[Oxford Comma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma)* (ein Komma nach dem letzten Element einer Aufzählung) existiert im Deutschen nicht und wäre falsch.

Genau dieses *Oxford Comma* ist ein schönes Beispiel für die stilgesteuerte Zeichensetzung im Englischen - Viele Stilregeln im englischen Sprachraum (z.B. der *[AP Styleguide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AP_Stylebook)*) verlangen dieses Komma **nicht**. Im Deutschen gibt es für die Zeichensetzung dagegen genau einen Satz anerkannte Regeln - früher die der Duden-Redaktion, heute die [Regeln des Rechtschreibrats](https://www.rechtschreibrat.com).

Comment: Naja, im Deutschen basiert die Kommasetzung auch auf Sprachrhythmik, nur wurde das irgendwann mal in grammatische Regeln gegossen und so konserviert.

Comment: @Janka - An sich nicht. Gerade das Oxford-Komma ist eine Stelle, wo man auch im Deutschen eine Zäsur in den Sprechrhythmus einbaut - Trotzdem steht da kein Komma.

Comment: Das Oxford-Komma würde zwischen Eleganz und stehen, warum gibt es nach Fragen kein Komma?

Comment: *Trotz ... Fragen* ist eine *adverbiale Ergänzung* (also kein *Nebensatz*)- Die bekommt im Deutschen kein Komma.

Comment: Eine Menge Kommafehler im Deutschen dürften darauf zurückgehen, dass Schreiber "nach Gefühl" Kommata einfügen, wo sie Sprechpausen machen würden, statt sich wie vorgeschrieben nur an der Grammatik zu orientieren. Prominentes Beispiel ist das Schild "Freibier, gibt's morgen" in etlichen Wirtshäusern - das Komma ist falsch, trotzdem begegnet man dem Spruch praktisch nur in dieser Form.

Comment: @RHa Das ist richtig und wohl ein grundsätzliches Missverständnis. Aber viel wichtigere Frage: WO gibt's Freibier?

Comment: @tofro   Das Wo beim Freibier stellt sich als Frage nicht, denn das Morgen ist ein - jedenfalls aus Sicht des Schildes und des Wirts - grundsätzlich unerreichbarer Zeitpunkt.

Comment: @Rha: Das muss dann aber eine süddeutsche Eigenart sein, denn im Norden setzt **niemand** an dieser Stelle ein Komma. Dort ist im Norden ja auch keine Zäsur.

Answer (score 2):

Deutsche Kommaregeln für diesen Fall:

1) "Trotz" ist eine Präposition, das präpositionale Satzglied "trotz X" wird wie alle einfachen Satzglieder nicht mit einem Komma getrennt.

Also: "Trotz X beschreiben ...".

Das ist im Englischen anders, dort wird ein Einschub vor der SVO-Struktur mit einem Komma getrennt:

> Yesterday, I went to the cinema. (Gestern ging ich ins Kino).
>
> Despite her fear, she wrapped her arms around him. (Trotz ihrer Angst schlung sie ihre Arme um ihn.)

Man beachte die andere Wortstellung im Deutschen: Ein Komma direkt vor dem Verb funktioniert einfach nicht. Im Englischen steht das Komma vor dem Subjekt, da geht es.

2) Die [Kommaregeln für Aufzählungen](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/komma#D100) sagen nur, dass *zwischen* den Gliedern der Aufzählung ein Komma steht (und keins bei "und"). Insbesondere steht nach der Aufzählung kein Komma (wenn man dort nicht aus anderen Gründen eins setzen muss.)

Also: "Trotz X, Y und Z beschreiben ...".

Answer (score 1):

Unterschiedliche Sprachen haben unterschiedliche Rechtschreib-, Aussprache-, Grammatik- und natürlich auch Zeichensetzungsregeln. Das beginnt bei der Frage, welches Zeichen wo steht, und endet bei der Frage, wir ein Zeichen im Text zu stehen hat.

Im Deutschen ist zum Beispiel die Trennung von Komposita, wir Ich es im ersten Satz praktiziert habe, Gang und Gäbe. Im Englischen habe ich sie bewusst noch nicht wahrgenommen. Im Französischen werden Ausrufe- und Fragezeichen mit einem Leerzeichen vom Wort abgesetzt, in anderen Sprachen gilt das als falsch. Japanisch und Chinesisch kennen eigentlich keine Leerzeichen, dementsprechend werden Punkte und Kommas kompress gesetzt (da die Schriftarten nichtproportional sind, sind die entsprechenden Zeichen ebenfalls breit und lassen zum nächsten Wort etwas mehr Platz). Im Europäischen Sprachen nennt man das Plenken und es ist auch falsch.

Die Kommaregeln sind insofern tückisch, als dass man sich mit ihnen nicht unbedingt beschäftigt – wobei ich mich schon an die eine oder andere Kommasetzregel im Französischunterricht erinnere. Grundsätzlich basieren die englischen Kommaregeln auf der Frage: Wo pausiere ich, so atme ich im Satz? Die deutschen hingegen sind vor Allem syntaktischer/grammatikalischer Natur. So werden Nebensätze im Deutschen immer durch Kommapaare abgetrennt, während im Englischen bei vielen Nebensätzen (vor Allem Relativsätzen) kein Komma stehen darf. Einzelne Satzteile werden im Deutschen fast nur dann abgetrennt, wenn sie ihr eigenes Verb haben (wichtigste Ausnahme: Apposition), während einleitende Orts- und Zeitangaben auf Englisch oft ein Komma nach sich ziehen.

Selbst bei Aufzählungen haben Deutsch und Englisch leicht unterschiedliche Regeln: Im Englischen kann das sogenannte *Oxford Comma* zwischen dem vorletzten Glied und *und* gesetzt werden. Im Deutschen wäre ein solches Komma falsch.